# Can I migrate power mac g5 settings and apps to a power book g4?

Tags: migration, migration-assistant, power-mac, powerbook

I would like to know because I am planning on purchasing a power book g4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your settings are transferable and will be transferred using Apple's Migration Assistant, Apps too and as the G5 and G4 are both Power PC apps your apps should transfer over as well.

You could even transfer your settings (but not your Apps) to a modern Intel-based Mac.